# How to generate code using jooq code generator with maven

Tags: sql-server, jooq

Hi I am trying to generate jooq code files without success. I am using intellij and maven to generate code. When I try an d generate the code nothing happens. I get this message: `[INFO] Generating catalogs : Total: 0`. I am using Sql server express with Jooq trial. Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Manage the plugin's dependency. In this example, we'll use a PostgreSQL database -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <!-- Specify the plugin configuration.
                     The configuration format is the same as for the standalone code generator -->
                <configuration>
                    <!--<logging>WARN</logging>-->
                    <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test</url>
                        <user>sa</user>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </jdbc>

                    <!-- Generator parameters -->
                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes></excludes>
                            <!--<inputCatalog>public</inputCatalog>-->
                            <inputSchema>dbo</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>mypackage</packageName>
                            <directory>mypath</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the output I get when trying to generate the files.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\projects\service "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59337:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 jooq-codegen:generate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.3:generate (default-cli) @ service ---
[INFO] Database                 : Inferring database org.jooq.util.sqlserver.SQLServerDatabase from URL jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;authentication=NotSpecified;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true;serverNameAsACE=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=test;columnEncryptionSetting=Disabled;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;
[INFO] No <inputCatalog/> was provided. Generating ALL available catalogs instead.
[INFO] License parameters       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Database parameters      
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   dialect                : SQLSERVER
[INFO]   URL                    : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;authentication=NotSpecified;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true;serverNameAsACE=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=test;columnEncryptionSetting=Disabled;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;
[INFO]   target dir             : [target dir]
[INFO]   target package         : com.test
[INFO]   includes               : [.*]
[INFO]   excludes               : []
[INFO]   includeExcludeColumns  : false
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] JavaGenerator parameters 
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   strategy               : class org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy
[INFO]   deprecated             : true
[INFO]   generated annotation   : true
[INFO]   JPA annotations        : false
[INFO]   validation annotations : false
[INFO]   instance fields        : true
[INFO]   sequences              : true
[INFO]   udts                   : true
[INFO]   routines               : true
[INFO]   tables                 : true
[INFO]   records                : true
[INFO]   pojos                  : false
[INFO]   immutable pojos        : false
[INFO]   interfaces             : false
[INFO]   immutable interfaces   : false
[INFO]   daos                   : false
[INFO]   relations              : true
[INFO]   table-valued functions : true
[INFO]   global references      : true
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Generation remarks       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                          
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@  @@  @@    @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@    @@  @@  @@@@  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@  @  @  @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@        @@        @@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Thank you for using the 30 day free jOOQ 3.9.3 trial edition

[INFO] Generating catalogs      : Total: 0
[INFO] Removing excess files    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.214 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-04T18:10:46-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is how I am running the generator tool;

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in jOOQ 3.9.3: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6064

You have to specify an `<inputCatalog/>` if you want to specify an `<inputSchema/>` as well. The catalog is the name of your database.